# Php mailing script issue

Tags: php, database, phpmailer

I have used a mailing script in my payment-status.php file.
I'm using a payment gateway API where a user fills up the html form with all his details like Phone no, e-mail , address etc after the payment is done and successful it updates in database in table named "billing" under 'transaction_status'

Problem is that the mailer script is not able to fetch the user e-mail id from database where the transaction is successful.
And transaction successful status is stored in different table not in one where user details are stored.

the query that should have being used to fetch e-mail id from user who's transaction is successful should be some thing like this

$sql_query="Select email from billing_guest where transaction_status="transaction successful"

This is the mailing script that I used.

```
$query  = "SELECT email FROM billing_guests WHERE email = '" . $_POST["email"] . "'";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $entry = mysql_num_rows($result);
  //Check if entry exists
  if($entry !== 0){
    $message = $data['email'];
    $to = "$_POST["email"]" ;
    $from = "domain-id";  
    $Subject = "Hi";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-885n-l\r\n";

    $headers .= "From: $from\r\n";
    $message .="Thank You";

    if(mail($to, $from, $subject, $message, $headers)){
      echo 'Email sent';
    }else{
      echo 'Failed sending email';
    }
  }else{
    echo 'No email entry found';
  }                    
  mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: Apart from the huge security hole, `"SELECT email FROM...WHERE email.."` isn't a bit redundant?

Comment: Looks like it would be better off using `COUNT(*)` instead of getting the email address. You're right about [the huge security hole](http://bobby-tables.com/) though.

Comment: Yeah, I just phrased it badly, but I meant that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a synthax error here:

```
$to = "$_POST["email"]" ;
```

change that line to

```
$to = $_POST["email"];
```

And also the parameters to the mail function are

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)
```